# from where can i download "pipeline" plugin for jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have searched for the download links to download the **pipeline** plugin for jenkins,but i'm unable to find it.

I tried in this link : https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/
but i dint get any.
can any one help me out ?

Comment: Are you unable to install plugins from within Jenkins?

Comment: Here is a quite good article about complete Jenkins plugin handling: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

I think this link you need: https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-aggregator

Or you go to Plugin Manager in jenkins, select tab "available" and fill "**Pipeline**", you can see like this: [Pipeline Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WvBk.jpg)